# Running multiple timestamps on the one Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I have a spreadsheet with a sheet called Team Allocation sheet. I want two timestamps; one when any cell in column A = “9. Closed/Handed over”, timestamp to go one cell to the right. The other timestamp is required when a value is entered into any cell in column L, the timestamp to be entered 4 cells to the right.

Have each working individually, but not together.

No experience with coding/google scripts. Any assistance appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Team Allocation sheet");
  myFunction1();
  if ([11].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
    e.range.offset(0, 4).setValue(new Date());
    myFunction2();
    if ([1].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1 || ['9. Closed/Handed over'].indexOf(e.value) == -1) return;
e.range.offset(0, 1)
    .setValue(new Date());}
  }
```

Script editor says:

```
ReferenceError: "myFunction1" is not defined. (line 4, file "Code")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Team Allocation sheet" ) { 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}
if( r.getColumn() == 12 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 4);
  var newDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate1);
}
}
}
```

Comment: this works. Amended to  "GMT+10", "dd/MM/yyyy"); for my purposes. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two functions. You need two `if` statements in the same function.

I would also suggest a check to make sure that the edit event is coming from the 'Team Allocation sheet'. Else you'll see time-stamps on this tab even if there is an edit made on some other tab.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName(); // Name of the sheet that got edited
  var column = e.range.columnStart;
  var value = e.value; // New value in cell after editing

  if ( name == "Team Allocation sheet" && value == "9. Closed/Handed over" && column == 1) {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
  }

  if ( name == "Team Allocation sheet" && column == 12) {
    e.range.offset(0, 4).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot get the column L part of this to work. Column A does. Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, the sheet name was incorrect for the column L `if` statement. Have edited it in the answer. Will you try again?